# Powershell Transfer files under multiple subfolders to another folder under same Document Library Sharepoint

Tags: powershell, script

I have a document library "Documents1" which has multiple folders (aa, bb,cc, dd, Redundant).

Trying to write a powershell script to move files placed in multiple sub folders to folder "redundant" under the same doc lib.

The files to be moved needs to be read from a .txt file which contains list of files names present under various sub folders.

```
$WebURL="test.com"
 $SourceLibrary ="/Documents1"
 $TargetLibrary = "/Documents1/Redundant"
 $filenames = Get-Content 'F:\users\filelist.txt' 

#Get Objects $Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
 $SourceFile = $Web.GetFile($SourceLibrary) 
$Targetfile = $Web.GetFolder($TargetLibrary)
 foreach ($file in $filenames) { 
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFile -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.name -match $file)} | Move-Item -Destination $Targetfile 
Write-Output "File moved " $file 
}
```

Comment: $_name shows blank not sure where am I going wrong

Comment: $web=Get-SPWeb "test.com"
    $listName="Documents1"
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$filelist=Get-Content "f:/users/filelist.txt"

$TargetFolder = $Web.Url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url + "/"+ "redundant"
$sourcefolder=$list.rootfolder.SubFolders["aa"]
$files = $sourcefolder.Files

foreach($name in $filelist) {
foreach ($item in  $files | Where-Object { $_["Name"] -like "*$name*" }) {
     $File=$Web.GetFile($Item.URL);
     $TargetPath=$TargetFolder+"/"+$file.name;
     $File.MoveTo($TargetPath);
     Write-Host "Moved Item:"$item.Name;
     }
}

Comment: error says cannot index into null array for  $_["Name"]